# Offline Map No such Module Mapbx Directions

Tags: ios, swift, offlineapps

For offline map I have seen this sdk

```
https://www.mapbox.com/mobile/#sdk
```

But When I Implement this in my project. It is showing error No such module Mapbox Directions. But Already I have add Mapbox Directions pod in my project. Please see the screen shot.[image]

Comment: Hello, I'm having the same issue here... Have you solved it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the frame work under General-> Embedded Binaries. This solved the issue for me many times, when I was adding the framework from PODS

Comment: My pod is pod 'MapboxDirections.swift', '~> 0.8'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,

Solution: -

```
 Add the frameworks in **Bridgefile**
```

Then the `$(SRCROOT)` in `BuildSettings -> SearchPath-> Framework Search path`